# How to link page scroll to a div element scroll? Or how to scroll div element using page scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an issue with scrolling the page and some div with content inside it.

There is a `.container` at the bottom of the page and footer goes after it.
When an user gets to the bottom of the page there should be possibility to continue scrolling the page but exactly the `.scrollable` container should be scrolled.

By default we can scroll `.scrollable` div's content if mouse cursor is over it. But I need to somehow link common page scroll to this `.scrollable` div's scroll.

How does this problem can be solved?

Here the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vk1a3fub/1/) link to make the issue more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    //scrolling bottom
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 <= 0) {
       //checks if we reached bottom
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $('.scrollable').scrollTop($('.scrollable').scrollTop() + 10);
        } 
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** After lots of digging I've managed to build a script for exactly what you need

**NOTE:** The event is currently bound on `mousewheel` but there are more types of scrolling such as: **dragging**, **clicking**, **arrow keys** and I'm not aware of function to cover them all and do the thing you want in the same time.

I forked your **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pu19fay/)**

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't need to sync page and div scroll. I need to continue scrolling when the user gets to the bottom. May be that should be done using CSS only? I don't know, unfortunately

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you. Updated.